# what's the meaning of "${0##*[\\/]}" in shell?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I got the question when i looking other's shell script.

I saw that declared

```sh
APP_NAME="${0##*[\\/]}"
```

Since I can't find any answer, what's the meaning of this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## It's [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to get script name itself, without path

See `bash` manual:

> `${parameter##word}`
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching)).
>
> If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted.

[Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching):

> `*`
>
> Matches any string, including the null string. When the `globstar` shell option is enabled, and ‘*’ is used in a filename expansion context
>
> `[…]`
>
> Matches any one of the enclosed characters.

## Explanation

`${parameter<...>}` expression means that you can expand shell parameters.

I.e. `${1:-"default_arg_value"}` will be expanded to `"default_arg_value"` if script running without arguments.

`0` - is a 0th argument, i.e. script name itself

`${0##<pattern>}` will delete longest matching to `<pattern>` part of `$0`

`*[\\/]` means any string that ends with `\` or `/` symbol.

So, `APP_NAME="${0##*[\\/]}"` means that `$APP_NAME` will be initialized by script name itself, without path.

## Sample

Let's suppose you have script `a/b/c/d/test.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "${0##*[\/]}"
echo "${1#*[\/]}"
echo "${2##[\/]}"
```

```sh
$ bash a/b/c/d/test.sh /tmp/e /tmp/ff
> test.sh
> tmp/e
> tmp/ff
```

Comment: oh,i know the meaning of "${0##/}"，but the "[\\/]" i feel perplexed，Is that regx?

Comment: added explanation

Comment: @Kangaroo016 It's a wildcard (or "glob") pattern. Similar to regex, but the syntax is different (simpler and less powerful). It's the same thing the shell uses for filename wildcard patterns, like `*.txt`.